# make selling substract product ingredients from inventory with average price C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've created a Restaurant POS that sells Sandwiches, I'm trying to figure out how to create a calculation which does the following as an example
Hotdog Sandwich chosen -----> substract from inventory the following
1 Bread
50gm Ketchup
25gm Mayo
2 Hotdog pieces
etc.
Currently the client enters purchases as follows, 5 packs of Hotdogs by typing Hotdog and 5 in quantity, but the hotdog pack contains 6 hotdog pieces
while when he types Ketchup, and 5 in quantity it means 5 bottles.

what I'm asking is the best way to do this, what should I do?

1. make a DB table that holds the detail of each ingredient? like 1 bottle of Ketchup = 300gm and 1 Hotdog pack = 6 pieces?
   Or
2. make the code in C# converts what the client enters into grams and units? like when he chooses Ketchup from comboBox and enters 1 bottle, the code converts it to 300gm?

the reason for doing this is for the client to know exactly the amount of ingredients in the inventory, and also to make the program calculate the exact cost of the Sandwich, so he code get the net profit displayed in the reports section

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the information in the database (solution 1) because you don't have to change your source code when he e.g. want's to use bottles of ketchup with 350 g.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point, but that will change the input method, so he would have to enter by units and grams instead of packs, right?

Comment: You can make it easier when define 1 time which incredients he needs for a hotdog and then your customer defines in your input method that he needs 10 hotdogs and you calcute how many bottles, sausages, mayo, etc he has to order. Just an idea.